# How do I check my website on this iPhone web browser when I don't have an iPhone?

Tags: browsers, browser-detecting

Someone has sent me a screenshot of a website I'm coding. I'm not a fan of iPhone so I have no idea which browser it is.

Here is the screenshot, so please let me know which browser is this and how to check my website on it. Is there a simulator on Ubuntu?

[image]

Comment: check in safari browser with window resized to match the iphone's display size.

Answer (score 1):

That is Safari on an iPhone.

I believe that the only real iOS simulator is the one that comes with Apple's Xcode, the IDE for OS X. However, I doubt that you need something that fully-fledged.

A quick Google search turned up [this site](http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/) which renders sites as if they were on an iPhone (it spoofs the user agent and renders the page with the same dimensions as the phone). This will work fine for just quickly checking out how a site will look.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone uses the Safari web browser.   There are a few ways to do testing from Ubuntu so you don't have to spend money on a new device.

You can install Safari for Windows under Wine on Ubuntu. I used the [Play on Linux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) to install it and run it successfully.  While it does allow you to do some browser testing using the correct rendering engine, it is a somewhat old version and renders very differently than the latest version on Apple products in many cases.

To test your website on a variety of platforms you can use web services such as [Browser Shots](https://browsershots.org/) or [Cross Browser Testing](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/).  The latter is a paid subscription service (to which I subscribe) that allows both screen shots and live sessions on all the popular browsers, platforms, and devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 helpful sites you should be using. Both options have free options for many purposes, have no required downloads/accounts, and are exceedingly useful.

- [www.MobileTest.me](http://www.MobileTest.me) - For mobile browsers. Just pick the phone you want to view an URL on and it shows right up.
- [www.Browsera.com](http://Browsera.com) - For desktop browsers. Shows which browsers / versions are most different from a baseline model of your site.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://www.browserstack.com Browserstack.  It's a pay service, but allows for debugging via the chrome inspector tools for iPhone and Android devices.  Additionally you can test on Mac or PC if you don't have one.  It's all browser based and live testing, so changes are reflected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

That is Mobile Safari (not that, AFAIK, all iOS web browsers use the same rendering engine). There is no good way to test it in outside of using an iPhone (or other iOS device).

The nearest you can come is to use the XCode [iOS simulator](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator.html), but even that requires a Mac to run it.

You could consider using another version of Safari, but: There are no versions of Safari for Linux. The Windows version of Safari (which you could run under WINE) has been discontinued and is very out of date. The Mac version of Safari won't run under Linux. All of them have differences from Mobile Safari.

Using another browser resized to the right dimensions won't give you the Mobile Safari rendering engine.